# Clang RecursiveASTVisitor skip AST nodes already traversed

Tags: for-loop, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to do some analysis on a ForStmt. So everytime I visit a ForStmt I do some analysis on the bounds, set up some other analysis variables then call TraverseStmt on its body for further analysis.

Once I return from my for statement, I do not want RecursiveASTVisitor to visit any statement inside the ForStmt.

```
virtual bool VisitForStmt(ForStmt *st) {
  /* Init analysis data */
  TraverseStmt(st->getBody());                                            
  /* Save analysis data */
  return true;
}

virtual bool VisitStmt(Stmt *st) {
  /* Collect analysis data */
  return true;
}
```

The problem is after returning from the ForStmt, RecursiveASTVisitor again goes on to traverse the statements inside the for loop. How do I mark the body of ForStmt as visited?

Thank You.

Comment: how about remember the source location of the body in VisitForStmt, then skip in VisitStmt if the current stmt is within the range?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Currently I set a flag before calling TraverseStmt and reset it after TraverseStmt returns. Then in VisitStmt I do analysis only when the flag is set, otherwise return true.

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: as long as you make sure the flags are guarding the same stmt. I mean `VisitStmt` traverses all stmts, and you only want to skip the forStmt that you visited.